# Getting the index path of a collection view that is inside of a tableviewcell and Segueing to a different VC

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, tableview, segue

So I have nested a UICollectionView inside of a tableview controller to display user profiles because when I was using a UICollectionViewController, it wouldn't let user use a horizontal scroll. I've been successful in display the data how I want. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rRLV.png)

However, I'm had a lot of trouble getting the selected index of the cell that I'm selecting and passing this values of the selected cell to another view controller. In my view controller class I have added this code:

```
 // proceeding segues that have been made in main.storyboard to another view controller
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 


        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestingTableView


        let index = cell2.collectionView.tag

        print(cell2.collectionView.tag)

        // if segue is guest ...
        if segue.identifier == "guest" {

            // call guestvc to access guest var
            let guestvc = segue.destination as! GuestCommunityViewVC

            // assign guest user inf to guest var
            guestvc.guest = communities[index] as! NSDictionary

            // new back button
            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            backItem.title = ""
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem


        }

    }
```

This code will allow me to segue to the new view controller. However,

```
cell2.collectionview.tag
```

only prints a value of zero. Therefore, no matter which cell I select in the collectionview, It will only load the profile of the first item in the collection view (because the value is 0)

However, in this part of my code (which is an extension of my viewcontroller):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 

        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestingTableView

        cell2.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        print(cell2.collectionView.tag)

}
```

Whenever I select a cell, I'm able to print the indexPath.row of the cell that is actually selected. However, if I run my segue from inside of this function, nothing will happen.

Does anyone know what I can do differently? I've struggled with this for a few days and any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Call `performSegue` in `didSelectItemAt`.

Please use like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 

    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestingTableView

    cell2.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

    print(cell2.collectionView.tag)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "guest",sender: self)
}
```

Comment: But how can I pass information over to the next view controller such as: guestvc.guest = communities[index] as! NSDictionary